# put a output file under a folder in ruby

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm using the line of code like below in Ruby to write log file when running a script to an output file like:

```
system("ruby #{file} > #{file}.out")
```

However, now I want to create a new folder, then expect to put the output file under this folder, I tried with the below way:

```
Dir::mkdir(directory_name)
system("ruby #{file} > directory_name/#{file}.out")
```

However, I does not observe the outfile put under folder "directory_name", anybody please guide me a way ? Thanks so much.

Comment: you have strange mix of technologies. if you are running ruby file using `system`, IMHO you should use bash

Comment: Is `directory_name` a variable, in which case you should write `#{directory_name}` in the second line? Or is it the name of the directory, in which case you should quote it in the first line?

Comment: @Thomas: great, your answer resolved my question quickly, yes, "directory_name" is a variable, and I wrote #{directory_name} as your suggestion to observe my expectation. thank you very much.

Comment: voted to close as too localized. This question is unlikely to help any future visitors

Comment: Agreed and voted likewise. But since I apparently answered the question I've put my comment as an answer.

Comment: Sure, and OP should accept it but still it should be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `directory_name` a variable, in which case you should write `#{directory_name}` in the second line? Or is it the name of the directory, in which case you should quote it in the first line?

Comment: I have modified my second line of code to: system("ruby #{file} > #{directory_name}/#{file}.out") as Thomas' suggestion, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have issues like this because the `system` command runs in its own shell - so the working directory may not be in context to the dir you made.

Generally, it's better not to mix unix strategies, if you can.

```
system("cd #{File.expand_path(directory_name)} && ruby #{file} > #{directory_name}/#{file}.out")
```